# I am trying to make the following static method it gives me an error

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I am trying the following code to make a generic method that resizes the array but it is giving me an error "non-static type variable T cannot be referenced from static context", Is there any way of making this method static still not having the error? Is there any other better way of doing it?? I am new to java and I am still learning so I am not sure if it will work or it is just my thinking that it will do the job for me?

```
    public static T[] resizeArray(T[] t,int newSize) { 
        Object[] temp = new Object[newSize];
        System.arraycopy(t, 0, temp, 0, t.length);
        t=(T[]) new Object[newSize];
        System.arraycopy(temp, 0, t, 0, t.length);
        return t;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the method generic with `<T>` after `static`, see also the signature of [`Arrays.copyOf(T[], int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-T:A-int-). Which *copies the specified array, truncating or padding with nulls (if necessary) so the copy has the specified length*. Something like,

```
public static <T> T[] resizeArray(T[] t, int newSize) {
    return Arrays.copyOf(t, newSize);
}
```

Comment: Nice! This is really helpful, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put type definition before return type

```
public static <T> T[] resizeArray(T[] t,int newSize)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it helps :)